# Добавить условие в функцию

Tags: php, wordpress, функции

Здравствуйте. Со скрипом постигаю азы php и вот:
добавил поддержки кастомного сайдбара на странице

```
   if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Футер на странице записи',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</div>',
    ));
```

и добавляем его в футер:

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Футер на странице записи") ) : ?>
```

в принципе, все хорошо и работает, но как добавить сюда проверку, является ли страница главной(выполнить, если не является), или хотя бы одиночная ли это страница(выполнить, если да)?
Я, вроде, все это нашел, помогите укомплектовать, пожалуйста.
Вот проверка на главную:

```
if( is_front_page() ){

}
else {
 // не главная
}
```

а вот на отдельный пост

`is_single();`

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С Wordpress никогда особо не работал, но предложу свой вариант. Надеюсь я Вас правильно понял

```
<?php //Проверяем, что страница не является главной или является отдельной страницей  ?>
<?php if (is_front_page() === false OR is_single() === true): ?>
    <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Футер на странице записи")) : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Великолепно! Это то, что нужно, хоть достаточно было только проверки на главную :) спасибо. На основе этого я смогу делать и другие проверки. Чтобы оставить только одно условие, нужно удалить === false OR is_single() ?

Comment: `OR is_single() === true` удалите

Comment: а, ну да, все понял, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

в глобальном массиве `$_SERVER` - в параметре `['REQUEST_URI']` содержится информация где ты находишься в данный момент. Можешь проверять эту переменную.

Comment: Спасибо, но, мне кажется, это слишком сложно. Мне ведь просто нужно правильно вписать код из третьего окна в строку из второго окна, с соблюдением синтаксиса.